# Configurar correctamente las columnas de la gráfica

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo una aplicación de escritorio de tipo Windows Form en C# la cual cuenta con un control de tipo `Chart`.

El siguiente código muestra la gráfica actual:

```
/// <summary>
/// Establecer valores a la gráfica.
/// </summary>
private void GenerarGrafica()
{
    // Valores de prueba.
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 10);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 8);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 9);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 5);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 2);
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(5, 6);
}
```

Y la imagen muestra los resultados:

*Imagen 1:*

[image: Resultados de la gráfica]

Cada serie del control `Chart` posee su color *(el cual es establecido automáticamente por el componente).*

Al cambiar el index de las series *(tal como se puede apreciar en el código)*:

```
/// <summary>
/// Establecer valores a la gráfica.
/// </summary>
private void GenerarGrafica()
{
    // Valores de prueba.
    chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 10);
    chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(1, 8);
    chart1.Series[2].Points.AddXY(2, 9);
    chart1.Series[3].Points.AddXY(3, 5);
    chart1.Series[4].Points.AddXY(4, 2);
    chart1.Series[5].Points.AddXY(5, 6);
}
```

Obtengo el siguiente resultado:

*Imagen 2:*

[image: Segundo resultado de la gráfica]

Estoy teniendo problemas para configurar el ancho y el color de las columnas de la gráfica.

He intentado diferentes configuraciones para crear las columnas de la gráfica tales como:

- Crear todas las columnas así: `chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 10);` resultado que todas las columnas estén unidas *(sin espacio entre ellas)*.
- Agregar una columna *falsa* para agregar espacio entre las columnas *así como se muestra en esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29459902/4092887)*.
- Esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2153710/4092887) muestra cómo establecer un espacio entre las columnas pero de una misma serie, y en mi caso particular, necesito que cada columna cuente con su serie individual *ya que así cada columna/serie posee un color diferente*.

Pero después de intentar e investigar otras fuentes, no he logrado obtener los resultados deseados.

**¿Cuál es la configuración correcta que se debe realizar para obtener las columnas del mismo ancho como se muestra en la *Imagen 1*, pero con los colores de *Imagen 2*?**

Answer (score 2):

Debes crear una sola serie (tu primer intento) y asignar un color a cada punto, o asignar una paleta personalizada a la serie.

### Asignar un color a cada punto:

```
private void GenerarGrafica()
{
  // Colores de prueba
  Color[] colores = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Orange, Color.Yellow, Color.Gold };
  // Valores de prueba.
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 10);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 8);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 9);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 5);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 2);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(5, 6);

  foreach (DataPoint point in chart1.Series.Points)
  {
    point.color = colores[series.Points.IndexOf(point)];
  }

}
```

### Asignar una Paleta Personalizada a la Serie:

Otra forma es asignar todos los colores por medio de una [paleta existente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartcolorpalette(v=vs.110).aspx) o una personalizada a la serie completa:

```
private void GenerarGrafica()
{
  // Colores de prueba
  Color[] colores = new Color[] { Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Orange, Color.Yellow, Color.Gold };
  // Valores de prueba.
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(0, 10);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(1, 8);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(2, 9);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(3, 5);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(4, 2);
  chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(5, 6);

  chart1.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None; 
  chart1.PaletteCustomColors = colores;

}
```

Si además quieres ajustar el ancho de las barras (y el espaciado entre ellas) intenta estableciendo esta propiedad:

```
chart1.Series[0]["PointWidth"] = "0.5"
```

El valor por defecto es "0.8", si colocas "1" no habrá espacio entre las barras (ancho máximo), y si colocas un numero menor disminuirá el ancho de las barras.

No tengo a mano VS para probar el código, pero debe funcionar.

*con información de:*

- http://forums.asp.net/t/1652369.aspx?How+Do+I+Assign+Individual+Colors+to+Bars+in+MS+Chart+Control
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alexgor/2009/10/06/setting-microsoft-chart-series-colors/
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd456700(v=vs.100).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd456764(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Esta será la última alternativa que vaya a contemplar, ya que _aunque no lo haya especificado en mi pregunta_ la información puede variar y _en cuanto a los colores_ debería generar la funcionalidad para validar que los colores para las columnas no se repitan.